# jQuery ajax function in external .js file will not call code-behind Webmethod

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have recently moved my JS functions from a masterpage to a seperate .js file.  Since doing this the ajax functions will not call the code-behind webmethod.

The function is called via the OnClientClick and the key/pair data values are there. However, the ajax will not call the webmethod from this external .js file. I have tried different forms of the url without success.

Can anyone explain to me why the ajax function will not call the code-behind webmethod?

Is this simply a Micorsoft "feature"?

### **.master**

```
<script src="/JavaScript/TreasurersChecksEE/TCEE.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

### **.aspx**

```
<asp:Button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ID="refundSearch" OnClientClick="refNum('txtRefNo'); saveDdlParms();" OnClick="btnRefundSearch_Click" TabIndex="0" runat="server" Text="Search" type="button" UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>
```

### **aspx.cs**

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static void SaveMyParameters(string ddlValue, string ddlText, string refund)
    {
        string refundNum    = refund;
        string issueTypeVal = ddlValue;
        string issueTypeTxt = ddlText;

        HttpContext.Current.Session["Refund Number"]    = refundNum;
        HttpContext.Current.Session["Issue Type Value"] = issueTypeVal;
        HttpContext.Current.Session["Issue Type Text"]  = issueTypeTxt;
    }
```

### **.js**

```
function saveDdlParms() {
$.ajax({
    url: "/TreasurersChecksEE.aspx/SaveMyParameters",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ ddlValue: issueTypeVal, ddlText: issueTypeTxt, refund: refundNo }),
    context: document.body
    //                ,success: function (response) {                    
    //                    response ? alert("No: " + num + " Txt: " + txt + " RefNo: " + refundNo ) : alert("It didn't work.");
    //                }
})
```

};

Comment: What happens in the `refNum` JavaScript function?

Comment: Can we assume the location is correct relative to the page? `src="/JavaScript/Tre....`

Comment: @Stryker - no need for that,  ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods only work for POST and automatically JSON encode their response.

Comment: Does the page method 500 or is there no network request for it?

Comment: Yes. I attempted adding the [ScriptMethod] decorator without success.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Remove the '/' in front of '/TreasurersChecksEE.aspx' in the URL. The URL should be url: "TreasurersChecksEE.aspx/SaveMyParameters"

Comment: I've used Fiddler and there is a request for the url. However, after I pass the ajax function, which should call/execute the webmethod, the page reloads and calls the onclick event associated with the button rather than firing off the webmethod first.

Comment: Vimalan, I have attempted to use different forms of the url: /TreasurersChecksEE.aspx/SaveMyParameters, TreasurersChecksEE.aspx/SaveMyParameters, ~/TreasurersChecksEE.aspx/SaveMyParameters, .../TreasurersChecksEE.aspx/SaveMyParameters, without success

Comment: Karl Anderson the refNum function is separate it simply grabs a number and stores it as global variable for the ajax function to use: `function refNum(parm) {
        parm = 'cphPage_' + parm;
        refundNo = document.getElementById(parm).value;
    }`

Comment: @TheSchnitz, try adding an error callback to your ajax and see if it catches any exception. Example: error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {}

Comment: Vimalan, I added the error callback, and while it isn't catching an exception and displaying an error, it is now executing the webmethod. How strange!

Comment: **SOLVED:** Okay after performing some testing, I believe this snippet in the code behind is what makes this work properly `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]`  Thank you all for your suggestions and help with this solution!

Comment: Do you have JQuery script loaded?

Comment: Hi Gregg, sorry for the late reply. Yes I do have the JQuery script loaded.